# Progress bar to include in EJS

Tags: node.js, heroku, ejs, fast-csv

I am uploading a csv file using fast-csv and then submitting all its rows in fileRows Array.

Next I am rendering my webpage:

```
res.on('end', function () {
    res.render("execute", {fileRows})
  });
```

Here ejs is processing my file by matching with some values in database.

If my file is small ejs is processing what I want but if the file is big heroku is giving me timeout error as your page should load within 30 seconds.

So I was thinking of including a progress bar so that the website gets loaded and shows the user a progress bar until ejs is done processing and then displays the data. I tried using pace.js but it only runs when the process is completed. Therefore, it takes the same amount of time and displays a 0.2 second progress bar after the process then displays data which is of no use. I want it to run during the time res.render is executed.

please help

Comment: Can you include more information on how you are using pace.js to show the progress bar? It seems to me like you are running the progress bar logic after you make the process request which is causing the progress bar to show afterwards.